# error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in moc_testqt5.obj

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt5

I tried to compile a simple GUI application using Qt5.0.1 in Visual Studio 2012 but the following error occurred :

```
qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in moc_testqt5.obj
```

How to fix this problem ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are using libraries for VS 2010 in VS 2012. If you want to build your program with VS 2012, you'll need to get or build libraries for VS 2012.